# I am facing an error while running docker file locally

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, create-react-app

Here is my docker file for **create-react-app**

```
# Stage 1 - the build process 
FROM node:8.10 as build-deps
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build
# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:1.12-alpine
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

So when I am running the command -

> sudo docker build -t react-docker

I am facing this issue :-

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.17MB
Step 1/10 : FROM node:8.10 as build-deps
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host
```

Can you please help me with this issue. On the first step only it is throwing error I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like docker was set to use a proxy (by mistake)?

If it's intentional but has a typo, fix it, otherwise remove it.

Look for it with:

```
systemctl show --property=Environment docker
```

If found, fix/(or comment it out), flush, restart, check

More details : https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

Another place to check where it might be set:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
```

Comment: Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/
getting after running 
**systemctl show --property=Environment docker**